Sorting rows in a special order based on lookup table values
In the query below, when column in  DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY  m_id) is one of the main table columns, I get the result I want. Something like



m_id
m_txt
s_txt
s_date
sys_rank




1
item 1
NULL
null
1


2
item 2
SubItem 2-3
1/1/2020
2


2
item 2
SubItem 2-2
10/11/2025
2


2
item 2
SubItem 2-1
7/1/2023
2


3
item 3
NULL
null
3


4
item 4
SubItem 4-3
3/1/2020
4


4
item 4
SubItem 4-2
5/1/2020
4


4
item 4
SubItem 4-1
3/1/2026
4



This is what I want because I want to [dense] rank by m_id. Eventually, I will select top 10 ranks or ranks between 21 and 30 to get 10 items. Same works for DESC.
But if I try to Order by s_date or s_date desc from the lookup table, this is when I'm having a problem.
Question - is it possible to get result like this (below)? Here I really care that items under same ID are listed one after another and in each such group the top date is listed first.. ?? I can't think anymore, how I can achieve this result. Thanks



m_id
m_txt
s_txt
s_date
sys_rank




4
item 4
SubItem 4-1
3/1/2026
1


4
item 4
SubItem 4-2
5/1/2020
1


4
item 4
SubItem 4-3
3/1/2020
1


2
item 2
SubItem 2-2
10/11/2025
2


2
item 2
SubItem 2-1
7/1/2023
2


2
item 2
SubItem 2-3
1/1/2020
2


1
item 1
NULL
null
3


3
item 3
NULL
null
4



SELECT
   Outer_Tbl_Alias.*,
   sys___max_rank AS sys___countAllFoundRecords

FROM
(
    SELECT Rank_tbl_Alias.*,
        MAX(sys___rank) OVER() AS sys___max_rank
    FROM
    ( 
        SELECT
            Union_Tbl_Alias.*,
            DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY  m_id) AS sys___rank
        FROM
        (
SELECT 
   PerfData1.id m_id,
   PerfData1.c1 m_txt,
   PerfData2.c1 s_txt,
   PerfData2.d  s_date
FROM 
  PerfData1   left Join 
  PerfData2   On PerfData1.id = PerfData2.fkid    
WHERE (1 = 1) AND
   PerfData1.id < 200 

UNION

SELECT 
   PerfData3.id m_id,
   PerfData3.c1 m_txt,
   PerfData4.c1 s_txt,
   PerfData4.d  s_date
FROM 
  PerfData3  left Join 
  PerfData4  On PerfData3.id = PerfData4.fkid    
WHERE (1 = 1) AND
   PerfData3.id > 800

) Union_Tbl_Alias
ORDER BY
    m_id
OFFSET 0 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 950 ROWS ONLY    ) Rank_tbl_Alias
) Outer_Tbl_Alias

-- generate structure
create table PerfData1 (id int primary key, c1 varchar(100));
create table PerfData2 (id int identity primary key, fkId int, c1 varchar(100), d datetime, FOREIGN KEY (fkId) REFERENCES PerfData1(id));
create table PerfData3 (id int primary key, c1 varchar(100));
create table PerfData4 (id int identity primary key, fkId int, c1 varchar(100), d datetime, FOREIGN KEY (fkId) REFERENCES PerfData3(id));

-- generate data
DECLARE @id INTEGER = 0, @date datetime = GetDate();
begin 
    WHILE @id <= 10000
    BEGIN
        SET @id = @id + 1; 
        insert into PerfData1 (id, c1) values (@id, concat( 'item ', @id) );

        if @id % 2 = 0
        begin
            SET @date = DateAdd(minute, abs(rand() * 10000), GetDate());
            insert into PerfData2 (fkId, c1, d) values (@id, concat( 'SubItem ', @id, '-', 1), @date);
             SET @date = DateAdd(minute, abs(rand() * 100000), GetDate());
            insert into PerfData2 (fkId, c1, d) values (@id, concat( 'SubItem ', @id, '-', 2), @date);
             SET @date = DateAdd(minute, abs(rand() * 200000), GetDate());
            insert into .PerfData2 (fkId, c1, d) values (@id, concat( 'SubItem ', @id, '-', 3), @date);
        end;
    END;
end;


You can do:
with
q as (
  -- your query here
),
r as (
  select x.*, row_number() over(order by md desc, sys_rank) as new_rank
  from (
    select sys_rank, max(s_date) as md from q group by sys_rank
  ) x
)
select q.*, r.new_rank
from q
join r on r.sys_rank = q.sys_rank
order by r.new_rank, q.s_date desc

Result:
 m_id  m_txt   s_txt        s_date      sys_rank  new_rank 
 ----- ------- ------------ ----------- --------- -------- 
 4     item 4  SubItem 4-1  2026-03-01  4         1        
 4     item 4  SubItem 4-2  2020-05-01  4         1        
 4     item 4  SubItem 4-3  2020-03-01  4         1        
 2     item 2  SubItem 2-2  2025-10-11  2         2        
 2     item 2  SubItem 2-1  2023-07-01  2         2        
 2     item 2  SubItem 2-3  2020-01-01  2         2        
 1     item 1  null         null        1         3        
 3     item 3  null         null        3         4        

See running example at db<>fiddle.

Thank you. I will evaluate how I can fit this into my model

This works, bad news, I am no longer required to go into this direction. Thanks
